# (NotesView)How to catch the specific value in the field?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, notesview

I have many notes documents, there are all have a form, like this(the ACTION, TIME, USER not in the same):

[image]

Now I need to show the "FORWARD" of the ACTION in the Notes View, also the time and user.

Is any formula in Notes View can use to catch the specific value in the field and show it? Like "FORWARD"

The view is for the "FORWARD" of the ACTION log.

The view will like this:

[image]

Comment: Is each column on the form a single multi-valued field?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz The ACTION, TIME, and USER are single multi-valued field

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will require two steps. First, you need to find which position the "FORWARD" is in the list of actions.  Then you will need to use the position as an index in the list of times and in the list of names.

This will look something like this in your Time column:

```
Position := @member("FORWARD", actionFieldNameGoesHere);
timeFieldNameGoesHere(Position);
```

Your Name column will be the same, except that you'll use the name field name on the second line instead of the time field.